# Using current_user and other Devise Helpers in the rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I want to call `current_user` in the rails console to ensure a user is logged in.  When I write it though, I get the following error:

```
1.9.3p393 :045 > current_user
NameError: undefined local variable or method `current_user' for main:Object
```

How do I include the appropriate module that would let me use this method?

Comment: current_user gets the information from the session. There is no access to session from your console.

Comment: Ah well, I will have to debug around this issue then

Comment: Have you looked at [pry-rails](https://github.com/rweng/pry-rails) and [`binding.pry`](https://github.com/pry/pry#runtime-invocation)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best thing would be to use `pry gem`. Once you install it, just add the line pry to your controller and you can access `current_user`. You **cannot** access `current_user` from console in any other way **since it is session based**.