# current_user method with devise from the console

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise

```
rails 3.2.18
devise
pry-rails gem (which installs pry)
pry-doc gem
```

I started up the rails console:

```
rails c
```

Then I logged in:

Then I logged in:

```
[13] pry(main)> ApplicationController.allow_forgery_protection = false
=> false
[14] pry(main)> app.post('/sign_in', {"user"=>{"login"=>"p3.rails.production@gmail.com", "password"=>"Vw#98052"}})
=> 302
```

302 means I successfully logged in, which means I can call:

```
[15] pry(main)> app.controller.current_user
```

But I am getting the following response:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `current_user' for #<Devise::FailureApp:0x000000094e33c0>
from (pry):13:in `__pry__'

[16] pry(main)> app.session
```

Gives me:

```
=> {"flash"=>
  #<ActionDispatch::Flash::FlashHash:0x00000009509598
   @closed=false,
   @flashes={:alert=>"You need to sign in or sign up before continuing."},
   @now=nil,
   @used=#<Set: {}>>}
```

Comment: Console == No session == No User See this workaround:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/18325287/2011580  Apparently too trivial to warrant being considered an answer by the software here.  Of course shortly your question will be flagged as a duplicate if not removed entirely.

Comment: what happens if you try this: current_user = User.find(app.session["warden.user.user.key"][1][0])

Comment: I've already tried this (it's on stackoverflow from 2012), and I get a NoMethodError: undefined method [] for nil:NilClass, because there is no session, even though I am getting a 302